# How can I make an unique list cells?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a txt file which looks like below including 4 rows as an example and each row strings are separated by a `,`.

```
"India1,India2,myIndia     "
"Where,Here,Here   "
"Here,Where,India,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cee79db7029a7d4e46cc4a7e92c59c50

the file can be downloaded from here

I want to extract all unique cells across all , the output2

```
   India1
   India2
   myIndia
   Where
   Here
   India
   uyete
   AFD 
   TTT
```

I tried to read line by line and print it ìf i call my data as df`

```
myfile = open("df.txt")
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
   print lines
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "TTT" in the unique cells output?

Comment: @rassar Yes thanks, I updated it

Comment: So, that `.xls` file is essentially plain text containing the data? Or it's a fully formatted Excel document?

Comment: txt, xls or csv format?

Comment: Use the `csv` module to read the file of comma-separated-values and use `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations of pairs of them.

Comment: @eyllanesc does not matter. Any format is fine

Comment: Why are `A` and `B` not in the output?

Comment: @nik We want to help, but your question is still confusing. 1. A text file will require a different solution than an Excel document, so if the format doesn't matter or the format is a text file, will you edit the question to make that clear? 2. You say you want to extract "unique" cells; does that mean that if `AFD` appeared twice, you want it to appear only once in your output? If so, will you update your example to include a duplicate? 3. You haven't listed `A` and `B` in the output, shouldn't they be there, or are they column headers?

Comment: Great, thanks, this is better.

Comment: @nik is order important?

Comment: @Paul Rooney Yes Paul

Comment: Many thanks )  Gentle reminder: if you are content with any answer and wish to award your bounty to anyone, you have a few day to manually do so before it expires for all parties.  Take care @nik.

Comment: @pylang  I gave you the +50

Comment: Much appreciated @nik :)  Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: `.csv`, `.txt` Files**

Native Python is unable to read `.xls` files.  If you convert your file(s) to `.csv` or `.txt`, you can use the `csv` module within the Standard Library:

```
# `csv` module, Standard Library
import csv

filepath = "./test.csv"

with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)                                  # skip 'A', 'B'
    items = set()
    for line in reader:
        line = [word.replace(" ", "") for word in line if word]
        line = filter(str.strip, line)
        items.update(line)

print(list(items))
# ['uyete', 'NHYG', 'QHD', 'SGDH', 'AFD', 'DNGS', 'lkd', 'TTT']
```

---

**Option 2: `.xls`, `.xlsx` Files**

If you want to retain the original `.xls` format, you have to install a [third-party module](http://www.python-excel.org/) to [handle Excel files](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/).

Install `xlrd` from the command prompt:

```
pip install xlrd
```

In Python:

```
# `xlrd` module, third-party
import itertools
import xlrd

filepath = "./test.xls"

with xlrd.open_workbook(filepath) as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)                 # assumes first sheet
    rows = (worksheet.row_values(i) for i in range(1, worksheet.nrows))
    cells = itertools.chain.from_iterable(rows)
    items = list({val.replace(" ", "") for val in cells if val})

print(list(items))
# ['uyete', 'NHYG', 'QHD', 'SGDH', 'AFD', 'DNGS', 'lkd', 'TTT']
```

---

**Option 3: DataFrames**

You can handle csv and text files with pandas DataFrames.  [See documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for other formats.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Using data from gist.github.com/anonymous/a822647a00087abc12de3053c700b9a8
filepath = "./test2.txt"

# Determines columns from the first line, so add commas in text file, else may throw an error
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=",", header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
df = df.replace(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]+", np.nan, regex=True)      # remove special chars    
stack = df.stack()
clean_df = pd.Series(stack.unique())
clean_df
```

DataFrame Output

```
0     India1
1     India2
2    myIndia
3      Where
4       Here
5      India
6      uyete
7        AFD
8        TTT
dtype: object
```

Save as Files

```
# Save as .txt or .csv without index, optional

# target = "./output.csv"
target = "./output.txt"
clean_df.to_csv(target, index=False)
```

Note: Results from options 1 & 2 can be converted to unordered, pandas columnar objects too with `pd.Series(list(items))`.

**Finally: As a Script**

Save any of the three options above in a function (`stack`) within a file (named `restack.py`).  Save this script to a directory.

```
# restack.py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def stack(filepath, save=False, target="./output.txt"):
    # Using data from gist.github.com/anonymous/a822647a00087abc12de3053c700b9a8

    # Determines columns from the first line, so add commas in text file, else may throw an error
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=",", header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
    df = df.replace(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]+", np.nan, regex=True)      # remove special chars    
    stack = df.stack()
    clean_df = pd.Series(stack.unique())

    if save:
        clean_df.to_csv(target, index=False)
        print("Your results have been saved to '{}'".format(target))

    return clean_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set up input prompts
    msg1 = "Enter path to input file e.g. ./test.txt: "
    msg2 = "Save results to a file? y/[n]: "

    try:
        # Python 2
        fp = raw_input(msg1)
        result = raw_input(msg2)
    except NameError:
        # Python 3
        fp = input(msg1)
        result = input(msg2)

    if result.startswith("y"):
        save = True
    else:
        save = False

    print(stack(fp, save=save))
```

From its working directory, run the script via commandline.  Answer the prompts:

```
> python restack.py 

Enter path to input file e.g. ./test.txt: ./@data/test2.txt
Save results to a file? y/[n]: y
Your results have been saved to './output.txt'
```

Your results should print in you console and optionally save to a file `output.txt`.  Adjust any parameters to suit your interests.

Comment: I have updated the solution with a DataFrame option using pandas.  1) I included regex to ignore special characters.  Adjust accordingly.  2) You can convert the list to almost any format.  It unclear how you want to display your output (e.g. in REPL or in a new file).  The DataFrame  section includes both options and works with csv also.  3) These solutions assume you have clean data.  I noticed an issue with your latest txt file; the first line needed a trailing comma `India1,India2,myIndia,   `.   If you get errors or truncated data, consider csv format which is more reliable.

Comment: I really want your solution but the problem is that it is not generating any output for me. I use the last code. I use the shared data above (in my question) It runs but no output, no error nothing. What could be the reason? I am using Mac and Python 2.7

Comment: did you look it up?

Comment: It can be a long list of things, e.g. installation, IDE, environment, etc.  I ran this in Jupyter (recommended) installed via conda in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.  I also tried it in ipython console and native Python in 2.7.  I got the same results and outputs in each.  You can try saving the outputs (last lines or last example), and search for the target filenames on your system.  If you would like some assistance with setup, we may discuss this in a separate chat to reduce clutter here.

Comment: I believe that I must accept your answer because you have spent too much time on this. however, I need something. first of all, I am using `pyCharm` because I am a mac user . secondly I want to know if you can help me to make it as a function? for example , I want to save it to a folder and Run it based on a line command with input. how can i do this ?

Comment: You are not obligated to accept my answer.  I am willing to help.  So I am unfamiliar with how PyCharm sets up environments on you system, but you can still test this code in your commandline using native Python.  As for simple functions, you can run it from python no problem.  See above for updates.  And Merry Christmas :)

Comment: i liked and accepted your answer . Merry Christmas Dear and wish you all the  best @pylang

Answer (score 1):

If your `stack.txt` file looks like this (i.e. it's saved as a `.txt` file):

```
"India1,India2,myIndia     "
"Where,Here,Here   "
"Here,Where,India,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

The solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("stack.txt", "r") as f:
    # read your data in and strip off any new-line characters
    data = [eval(line).strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    # get individual words into a list
    individual_elements = [word for row in data for word in row.split(",")]
    # remove duplicates and preserve order
    uniques = OrderedDict.fromkeys(individual_elements)   
    # convert from OrderedDict object to plain list
    final = [word for word in uniques]
```

To get your desired columnar output:

```
print("\n".join(final))
```

Which yields:

```
India1
India2
myIndia     
Where
Here   
India
uyete
AFD
TTT
```

Comment: This looks like a fine answer, but as per the update, you don't need to skip the first row.

Comment: I hadn't seen that.. Plus new input entirely. I've updated the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the whole code, but I'll give you some ideas.

First, you need to read all the lines of the file:

```
lines = open("file.txt").readlines()
```

Then, extract the data from each line:

```
lines = [line.split(",") for line in lines]
```

You can generate combinations with `itertools.combinations`. For each line, print the combinations of the line's elements.

You can get the unique elements with `set` if you don't care about the order of the elements. Before using `set`, you should flatten the list `lines` first, maybe using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: why then you down vote my question? if I knew how to do that, I would not ask

Comment: @nik: Asking others to write code for you isn't the only—nor necessarily the best—way to learn. You've had at least two people tell you the steps, need, so I suggest you invest your time in figuring out how to do them—maybe by reading the related documentation or finding a tutorial somewhere (there are many).

Comment: @ForceBru I am sorry but your solution did not help me . I reduce the question to only first part, if you consider to give me a better solution, I will accept. note that I read all the post on this web related to my question and also I did read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code for reading the text file line by line is fine. So you still need to

1. Split each line into "cells"
2. Remove duplicates

You can split each line into cells using `split`

```
line.split(',')
```

And you want to remove white space, so I would `strip` each cell:

```
[value.strip() for elem in line.split(',')]
```

And you can remove duplicates with `set`

```
set(cells)
```

Lastly, I think it's better to use `with` (a context manager) when reading files. Putting it all together:

```
with open('df.txt', 'r') as f:
    cells = []
    for line in f:
        cells += [value.strip() for value in line.split(',')]

cells = list(set(cells))
```

If you want to be more compact, you can do it in a single list comprehension:

```
with open('df.txt', 'r') as f:
    cells = list(set([value.strip() for line in f for value in line.split(',']))
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I use the last code as compact one

Comment: Yep, you're right, there's a typo. See if you can figure it out -- a missing parenthesis.