# string manipulation and adding values based on row they are

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a file text delimited file which I am trying to make binary combination per each line and giving the number of line to each pairs.

Here is an example (you can download it here too if you want https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4107418c63b88c6da44281a8ae7a321f)

```
"A,B     "
"AFD,DNGS,SGDH   "
"NHYG,QHD,lkd,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

I want to have it like this

```
A_1     B_1
AFD_2   DNGS_2
AFD_2   SGDH_2
DNGS_2  SGDH_2
NHYG_3  QHD_3
NHYG_3  lkd_3
NHYG_3  uyete_3
QHD_3   lkd_3
QHD_3   uyete_3
lkd_3   uyete_3
AFD_4   TTT_4
```

It means, A_1 and B_1 are coming from the first row 
AFD_2 & DNGS_2 are coming from the second row , etc etc

I have tried to do it but I cannot figure it out

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools
# make my output
out = {}
# give a name to my data 
file_name = 'data.txt'
# read all the lines 
for n, line in enumerate(open(file_name).readlines()):
    # split each line by comma
    item1 = line.split('\t')
    # split each stirg from another one by a comma
    item2 = item1.split(',')
    # iterate over all combinations of 2 strings
    for i in itertools.combinations(item2,2):
        # save the data into out 
        out.write('\t'.join(i))
```

## Output Answer 1

```
"A_1,   B     "_1
"AFD_2, DNGS_2
"AFD_2, SGDH   "_2
DNGS_2, SGDH   "_2
"NHYG_3,    QHD_3
"NHYG_3,    lkd_3
"NHYG_3,    uyete"_3
QHD_3,  lkd_3
QHD_3,  uyete"_3
lkd_3,  uyete"_3
"AFD_4, TTT"_4
```

## answer 2

```
"A_1    B     "_1
"AFD_2  DNGS_2
"AFD_2  SGDH   "_2
DNGS_2  SGDH   "_2
"NHYG_3 QHD_3
"NHYG_3 lkd_3
"NHYG_3 uyete"_3
QHD_3   lkd_3
QHD_3   uyete"_3
lkd_3   uyete"_3
"AFD_4  TTT"_4
```

Comment: plenty of confusion here. Firstly why the split on tabs? Where are you expecting tabs in your input file? Also you appear to be attempting to `write` to a dictionary. Did you intend to have an output file?

Comment: @Paul Rooney sorry for confusion. I try to split lines from each other and that is why i use the tab, maybe I am wrong ? I just want to writ the output , I will modify that above

Comment: The lines are separated by newline i.e `\n`. Your `splitlines` function shoudl take care of that.

Comment: @Paul Rooney so please give me a solution if you can

Comment: @Paul Rooney you mean I use item1 = line.split('\n') instead ('\t')

Comment: `# split each line by comma`... Um, that's not what the code does

Comment: does your input file actually have those double quotes in?

Comment: And `out.write` definitely does my work for a set / dictionary object, so please provide the actual error message of this code

Comment: @Paul Rooney I just save it from xls to tab delimited text. normally in xlsx they don't have those

Comment: @cricket_007 there are a lot of error :-D if you want I can make it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from itertools import combinations

with open('data1.txt') as f:
    result = []
    for n, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        items = line.strip().split(',')

        x = [['%s_%d' % (x, n) for x in item] for item in combinations(items, 2)]
        result.append(x)

for res in result:
    for elem in res:
        print(',\t'.join(elem))
```

You need a list of list of lists to represent each pair. You can build them using a list comprehension in a loop.

I wasn't sure what you wanted as your actual output format, but this prints your expected output.

If there are quotes in the input file, the simple fix is

```
items = line.replace("\"", "").strip().split(',')
```

For the above code. This would break if there were other double quotes in the data. So if you know there aren't its ok.

Otherwise, create a small function to strip the quotes. This example also writes to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from itertools import combinations

def remquotes(s):
    beg, end = 0, len(s)
    if s[0] == '"': beg = 1
    if s[-1] == '"': end = -1
    return s[beg:end]

with open('data1.txt') as f:
    result = []
    for n, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        items = remquotes(line.strip()).strip().split(',')

        x = [['%s_%d' % (x, n) for x in item] for item in combinations(items, 2)]
        result.append(x)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for res in result:
        for elem in res:                
            linestr = ',\t'.join(elem)
            print(linestr)
            fout.write(linestr + '\n')
```

Comment: look at above, I posted the output , how it looks , I saved again the data from xls and it seems to have the double quote too

Comment: ok my answer was based on the assumption that the quotes were gone.

Comment: can I directly read them from `xlsx` ? they are all in first sheet and first column

Comment: There are python libraries for reading xlsx. You can try using them.

Comment: it is very strange because sometimes it put the value and sometimes it does not !!! when I use a larger data. in any case, how can I write it to a file ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really following you. I think what is there outputs the required values does it not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130906/discussion-between-paul-rooney-and-nik).

Comment: If you found some time, please look at my question here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201194/how-can-i-make-an-unique-list-cells  I am off but when I come online if you help me I will also accept and like your answer

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer provided adding that based on the comments it looks like you actually wish to write to a tab-delimited text file instead of a dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools

file_name = 'data.txt'
out_file = 'out.txt'

with open(file_name) as infile, open(out_file, "w") as out:
  for n,line in enumerate(infile):
    row = [i + "_" + str(n+1) for i in line.strip().split(",")]
    for i in itertools.combinations(row,2):
      out.write('\t'.join(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: I pasted the output of your answer above, which is not exactly the same as I wish

Comment: I liked it anyway

Comment: If your file actually has `"` in them then use `line.strip('"').strip().split(",")`

Comment: third line from the bottom

Comment: apologies, use `line.replace("\"", "").strip().split(",")` as provided by @Paul Rooney

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work with a minimal amount of code:

```
import itertools

input_filename = 'data.txt'
output_filename = 'split_data.txt'

with open(input_filename, 'rt') as inp, open(output_filename, 'wt') as outp:
    for n, line in enumerate(inp, 1):
        items = ('{}_{}'.format(x.strip(), n) 
                    for x in line.replace('"', '').split(','))
        for combo in itertools.combinations(items, 2):
            outp.write('\t'.join(combo) + '\n')
```